# IncompatibleClassChangeError with grails rendering plugin 0.44

Tags: grails, plugins, pdf-rendering

I have grails 2.0.4 application with rendering plugin 0.44. It works fine in dev environment, however, fails in production with IncompatibleClassChangeError.

Looked into the jars to see if there are any duplicates or incompatibilities, couldn't trace anything suspicious. 
Tried with clean war (grails clean, war) but didn't help.

Both production and development test are running similar setup except java minor versions - java 1.6.0_65 (dev test/mac os) and java 1.6.0_30 (production/cent os).

Any help much appreciated, thanks!

Here is my BuildConfig.groovy:

```
plugins{

------

compile ":qrcode:0.3"
compile ":rendering:0.4.4"
}
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
    org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.exceptions.ControllerExecutionException: Executing action [our function] of controller [com.x.ourcontroller]  caused exception: Runtime error executing action
        at org.grails.jaxrs.web.JaxrsFilter.doFilterInternal(JaxrsFilter.java:46)
        at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
        at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
        at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:769)
        at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:698)
        at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:891)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.exceptions.ControllerExecutionException: Runtime error executing action
        ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError
        at grails.plugin.rendering.document.RenderEnvironment.init(RenderEnvironment.groovy:37)
        at grails.plugin.rendering.document.RenderEnvironment.with(RenderEnvironment.groovy:75)
        at grails.plugin.rendering.document.RenderEnvironment.with(RenderEnvironment.groovy:67)
        at grails.plugin.rendering.document.XhtmlDocumentService.generateXhtml(XhtmlDocumentService.groovy:64)
        at grails.plugin.rendering.document.XhtmlDocumentService.createDocument(XhtmlDocumentService.groovy:34)
        at grails.plugin.rendering.RenderingService.render(RenderingService.groovy:36)
        at grails.plugin.rendering.RenderingService.render(RenderingService.groovy:35)
        at grails.plugin.rendering.RenderingService.render(RenderingService.groovy:65)
        at RenderingGrailsPlugin$_closure3.doCall(RenderingGrailsPlugin.groovy:59)
        at com.xx.yy..
        ... 7 more
2014-03-19 20:55:52,025 [TP-Processor16] ERROR servlet.GrailsDispatcherServlet  - HandlerInterceptor.afterCompletion threw exception
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError
        at org.grails.jaxrs.web.JaxrsFilter.doFilterInternal(JaxrsFilter.java:46)
        at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
        at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
        at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:769)
        at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:698)
        at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:891)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
2014-03-19 20:55:52,026 [TP-Processor16] ERROR servlet.GrailsDispatcherServlet  - HandlerInterceptor.afterCompletion threw exception
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError
        at org.grails.jaxrs.web.JaxrsFilter.doFilterInternal(JaxrsFilter.java:46)
        at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
        at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
        at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:769)
        at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:698)
        at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:891)        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
```

Comment: *Executing action [our function] of controller [com.x.ourcontroller]  caused exception* - where do you get this from?

Comment: I took out our class name and method name added that text.

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError was happening due to a conflict between classes across different plugins with respect to MockHttpServletRequest and MockHttpServletResponse classes coming for jax-rs plugin. Tried the latest jax-rs plugin (0.9 for 2.0.x grails) which mentions  in release notes that these are removed. However, this version of plugin didn't fix the problem. Manually removed the mock directory under jax-rs plugin from the war and repackaging it as a workaround for now. Removing the mock/* files fixed the problem.